# ruby script/server not reading RAILS_ENV option

Tags: ruby, scripting, redmine

I tried to run

```
ruby script/server RAILS_ENV=production
```

but somehow it always try to read "development" config.. nothings wrong with RAKE XXX RAILS_ENV=production (trying to read production config).

Any idea how to troubleshoot?

I have my other rails app in the same machine and it works fine. The problem above only happen for redmine rails.

Thanks in advance.
-iwan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

script/server doesn't use RAILS_ENV.

Try `ruby script/server -e production`

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the first command was that the environment needs to be set prior to invoking the server, so:
RAILS_ENV="production" script/server

(although, as noted, appending "-e production" afterwards does the same thing)